# Running socket.io on a domain

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

How do I run socket.io on a domain because my code works on localhost:3000 but not on a domain?
Does this have to be public in some way so that it can be used from anywhere?

Please help me with this.
Thanks you!

## Script.js (client-side)

```
const socket = io("http://localhost:3000");
const messageContainer = document.getElementById('message-container')
const messageForm = document.getElementById('send-container')
const messageInput = document.getElementById('message-input')

const name = prompt('What is your name?')
appendMessage('You joined')
socket.emit('new-user', name)

socket.on('chat-message', data => {
  appendMessage(`${data.name}: ${data.message}`)
})

socket.on('user-connected', name => {
  appendMessage(`${name} connected`)
})

socket.on('user-disconnected', name => {
  appendMessage(`${name} disconnected`)
})

messageForm.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault()
  const message = messageInput.value
  appendMessage(`You: ${message}`)
  socket.emit('send-chat-message', message)
  messageInput.value = ''
})

function appendMessage(message) {
  const messageElement = document.createElement('div')
  messageElement.innerText = message
  messageContainer.append(messageElement)
}
```

## Server.js (server-side)

```
const io = require('socket.io')(3000, {
  cors: {
    origin: "*",
  },
});

console.log("Port 3000")

const users = {}

io.on('connection', socket => {
  socket.on('new-user', name => {
    users[socket.id] = name
    socket.broadcast.emit('user-connected', name)
  })
  socket.on('send-chat-message', message => {
    socket.broadcast.emit('chat-message', { message: message, name: users[socket.id] })
  })
  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    socket.broadcast.emit('user-disconnected', users[socket.id])
    delete users[socket.id]
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Change port to 80 (if you using http) or 443 (if you using https)

```
const io = require('socket.io')(80, {
  cors: {
    origin: "*",
  },
});
```

--

```
const socket = io("http://website.com:80");
```

Comment: I'm using https. I tested both but they don't work.

Comment: If you using https. You should create certificate for your server. For example Let's encrypt it is free certificate you can turn it by certbot

Comment: If you want to install a free certificate. I can describe to you in detail how to do this, I have been suffering during week. Write here if you want me to explain it to you.

Comment: And this will only work on ubuntu, I'm not sure about other software.

Comment: Please explain to me about the certificate